# Getting Data into Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hi I am pretty new to spark and I am trying to implement a simple spark streaming application using Meetup's [RSVP stream](http://meetup.github.io/stream/rsvpTicker/).

Any idea idea how to connect the stream to Spark Streaming?
I am trying out rawSocketStream but not sure what the parameters are(viz. port)
Thank you

Comment: That's just an HTML page, you need access to the raw stream.

Comment: @MariusSoutier Yes, the stream can be accessed using http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps
I want to know how to get that stream into Spark Streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use socketTextStream to get the stream: http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps

Lets see an example:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

// Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("meetup")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
// Create a DStream that will connect to http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps:80
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps", 80)
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This doesn't work. You'll get an java.net.UnknownHostException. A custom receiver needs to be created. One of the examples can be found here: https://github.com/actions/meetup-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/receiver/MeetupReceiver.scala